# Redirect to link from Html tag in android

Tags: android, html, android-studio

So i have a html string which contains a 
So after i set this in a text view in android
i need only the tag with the href tag inside of it to be clickable and then redirect it to the corresponding link . How can i do that.

```
        "<body style='background-color:lightgreen;'><b style='color:red;'>App</b><br/>ABC <a href='redirect'>XYZ</a> App. Lorum Ipsum.</body>"
```

I want the XYZ link above to be set in a text view for which i am Using

```
Html.fromHtml()
```

after this the text is set . I want the "XYZ" text to be clickable and redirect me to the corresponding link. How can that be done?

Comment: And why not aren't we using a webview? ... You know for displaying HTML...?

Comment: because it is just involves two lines which i get from conifg from somewhere

Comment: anyway i found the answe just had to set
textview.movementmethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java and not Kotlin, as you didn't point that out in your question, but this is the same idea.

If you want the textview to be clickable and have it work like a link

Use something like `Pattern` or `Substring` to manually parse the string to get the URL. (Bad idea)

Then set an `setOnClickListener` for the textView you want to redirect the user to. This should have an `Intent` and all that jazz in it.